# What is the cost of Google+ api billing after reaching limit?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-domains

I need help in knowing about what is the cost per requests after limit is exceeded(10,000requests/day)?
In console.developers.google.com I didn't find the pricing for google+ requests.
There is a service to increase the Quota of requests per day which is free service, but I don't need this increasing Quota. Anyhow please let me know about maximum increase in requests Quota also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google+ API only has the free quota. There is no billable extension quota.

In theory Google could increase the requests quota to just about anything assuming you can convince them it's for a good reason.

Comment: But I need one more thing to clarify, in the console.developers.google.com for our app there is an option to enable billing, mentioning that if our requests gets exceeded 10,000/day then billing will be enabled for the extra requests. So there is billing for googleplus requests, Is that right?? If so what is the approximate cost for these extra requests?  In https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing it is mentioned  that for 10,000 requests $0.5 is the cost for google app engine but they didn't mention for google+ api.

Comment: All apps have the option to enable billing but only a few select APIs actually support billing. The Google+ APIs do not support billing and will just start refusing requests if the quota is exceeded.